# BASH: express command not recognized

Tags: node.js

I've read other forums on installing express, I have run
`npm install express -g` on command prompt as admin.

I did this command a few times and restarted my computer multiple times but Express is still not recognized.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Express isn't a web server; it is a framework for building web servers.

The express package doesn't provide anything directly executable.

The [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) has a getting started guide.

If you aren't trying to do server-side programming using Node.js and just want an HTTP server, then [the http-server package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) may be more your speed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’ve already installed Node.js, create a directory to hold your application and make that your working directory.

then follow the below command

```
npm init
```

follow step press enter and after

```
npm install express
```

make **index.js** file paste below hello work program.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Now you can run file using below command

```
node index.js
```

Open your broswer and enter URL : http://localhost:3000/

You can display **Hello World!**

You have successfully installed node js and express js program.